# How to make a field visible (attachable) in the inspector but inaccessible through code (private-like)?

Tags: unity, serialization

Let's say I have a variable named `button` of type `Button` which is of course `System.Serializable`.

I want that variable to be assignable through the inspector, so I make it `public`:

```
public class SomeScript : MonoBehaviour{
    public Button button;
}
```

Which gives me that:

[image]

Now, I want to keep the code clean & secure (organized) and there's a real reason why I need to preserve the encapsulation.

I know that there are multiple ways of retrieving components on runtime like `transform.Find("Some/Genius/TypeUnsafe/Path")` or `GameObject.Find("3 seconds scene iteration").GetComponent(...).` I want to avoid that.

How do I mix a variable `private access` with it's `public access` in the inspector?

Comment: _Why_ do you want to make this field "secure"/what do you mean by that?  Note that I put that in quotes, because if code runs on the client machine, the client can do pretty much whatever they want with it.  `private` isn't really intended to prevent a third party from gaining access to a field, it's meant to provide a way to say "don't look behind the curtain at what I'm really doing" - that is, it's mostly a way to keep **you** from gaining access to it.

Comment: Yeah, I know what encapsulation is for! :D I build some kind of `UI`/`API` `MVC`/`MVVM` pattern for a huge application (a game client actually) and I had to separate the `UI` from the `API`. I needed to assign values through the inspector cause simply - there's no other way. `Find()` methods are type unsafe, and it's easier to put things together by dragging & dropping. It's really, really hard to build a classic, OOP framework with `Unity` and you have to look for hacky things like this.

Comment: Keep in mind that private doesn't keep the variable secure from other scripts. You cab akways reach it with reflection or some pointer trickery

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You're looking for the [SerializeField Attribute](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/SerializeField.html)

From the docs:

> Force Unity to serialize a private field.
>
> You will almost never need this. When Unity serializes your scripts, it will only serialize public fields. If in addition to that you also want Unity to serialize one of your private fields you can add the SerializeField attribute to the field.

Your code would then look like this:

```
public class SomeScript : MonoBehaviour{
    [SerializeField]
    private Button button;
}
```

Comment: for readability I generally write it all on one line: `[SerializeField] private Button button;`  I find that easier to scan when there's a bunch of fields in a row. Also, screw the docs for "you will almost never need this"; I totally do this all the time.

Answer (score 2):

You can show your private variable By adding *[**SerializeField**](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/SerializeField.html)* attribute before the variable. Something like this

```
[SerializeField]
private Button button;
```

The above variable will be displayed to your inspector but your other classes will unable to get it. **Conversely** you can also hide your public filed in inspector through [***HideInInspector***](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/HideInInspector.html) attribute. Something like this

```
[HideInInspector]
public Button button;
```

Your above variable will be accessible by your other script but it will not be displayed to inspector.